# Preferred method of referencing an Application Express item?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In Application Express, there are several methods of referring to an item's value in session state. Which one is preferred when working in a page process?

1. Bind variable syntax, like `:P1_MY_ITEM`
2. PL/SQL syntax, like: `V('P1_MY_ITEM')`
3. Substitution syntax, like: `&P1_MY_ITEM.`

#3 is not appropriate, I get that. #2 is the only option when referncing session state from within a stored procedure. But if you are working in a PL/SQL page process or validation from inside Apex, is there a reason to prefer #1 or #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select my_column
from   my_table
where  my_other_column = V('P1_MY_ITEM');
```

Above will call function V for every row in my_table, whereas ...

```
select my_column
from   my_table
where  my_other_column = :P1_MY_ITEM;
```

... just compares my_other_column to the static value of the bind variable. If there are lots of rows in my_table, there will potentially be a performance hit from calling V each time, so if a bind variable is available (which within Apex it always is), it makes sense to use it.